# C# Windows Service timer ticks more than one

Tags: c#, timer, windows-services

I'm trying to make a service that should execute my codes every second after my codes execution ends. But when I start the service and debug it, timer ticks more than one, I mean, my codes executed twice before first execution ends.

here is my codes ;

```
Timer timer1 = new Timer(1000);
bool _service_working = false;

    protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
    {
        timer1.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(runProcess);
        timer1.Enabled = true;
        timer1.Start();

        _service_working = false;
    }
    protected override void OnStop()
    {
        timer1.Enabled = false;
    }

    private void runProcess(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {

        try
        {

            if (_service_working == false)
            {
                timer1.Enabled=false;
                _service_working = true;

            }

            #region myCodes


        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            _logService.insert_log(1022, 2, ex.Message, "Path : runProcess");
        }
        finally
        {
            _service_working = false;
            timer1.Enabled = true;
        }

     }
```

When I debug it, timer ticks again at runProcess if block...

Comment: As a side note you should probably look at a scheduling system such as Quartz

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you're using `System.Timers.Timer` then `Timer` events are raised in a background thread usually which means without any locking your timer event methods can overlap.

An easy solution is to set `AutoReset` to `false` and instead in your timer event restart it once complete, for example:

```
private bool terminating;

public Service()
{
    terminating = false;

    timer = new Timer(1000);
    timer.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(runProcess);
    timer.Enabled = true;
    timer.AutoReset = false;
}

protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
{
    timer.Start();
}

protected override void OnStop()
{
    terminating = true;
    timer1.Stop();
}

private void runProcess(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
{
    // Do stuff

    if (!terminating)
        timer.Start(); // Restart timer
}
```